# Filter condition with date is not working in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a query where I want to filter with date parameter, so I wrote the below query.

`select * from changerequests where createdon = '12-04-14'and lastmodifiedon='17-05-14';`

The query executes with 0 rows fetched, while the table has so many records.

The data type for createdon and lastmodifiedon colum is `DATE`

Comment: You can convert the literals to `date'2014-04-12'` and `date'2014-05-17'` presuming the year part is at the end.

Comment: [Date Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1): *You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example: `DATE '1998-12-25'`. Alternatively you can specify an Oracle date value, as in the following example: `TO_DATE('98-DEC-25 17:30','YY-MON-DD HH24:MI')`*

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type that is composed of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human readable format.

> In my table the date is stored as `12-04-14`

No, if your columns are `DATE` data types then it does not store them using that format.

The client application you are using to access the database probably uses the `DD-MM-RR` format to **display** the date but it will be stored as binary data without any human readable formatting.

If you do:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(createdon, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TO_CHAR(lastmodifiedon, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   changerequests;
```

Then you should see the full components, including the time component, of the date.

---

When you do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   changerequests
WHERE  createdon = '12-04-14'
AND    lastmodifiedon = '17-05-14';
```

Then `'12-04-14'` is **NOT** a `DATE` data type; it is a string literal.

Oracle will try to be helpful and convert it to a date and your query is effectively:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   changerequests
WHERE  createdon = TO_DATE(
         '12-04-14',
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
AND    lastmodifiedon = TO_DATE(
         '17-05-14',
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       );
```

This does not match because the dates will be given a time component of midnight and the dates in your table probably have a non-midnight time component.

Instead, what you need to do is match on a time range over the full 24 hour period:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   changerequests
WHERE  createdon >= DATE '2014-04-12'
AND    createdon <  DATE '2014-04-13'
AND    lastmodifiedon >= DATE '2014-05-17'
AND    lastmodifiedon <  DATE '2014-05-18';
```

Or, use `TRUNC` to truncate the time components to midnight and then compare:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   changerequests
WHERE  TRUNC(createdon) = DATE '2014-04-12'
AND    TRUNC(lastmodifiedon) = DATE '2014-05-17';
```

(*Note: Using `TRUNC` will prevent Oracle from using an index on those columns and you would need a function-based index instead; using a date range will allow Oracle to use an index on those columns and is usually the preferred solution.*)

Answer (score 0):

What does `'12-04-14'` even mean? April 14, 2012? April 14, 1912? April 12, 2014? ...

It seems the DBMS makes a guess, but guesses different from what you are expecting.

When comparing dates, use date literals, not strings. E.g.:

```
select * 
from changerequests
where createdon = date '2014-04-12'
and lastmodifiedon = date '2014-05-17';
```

If this doesn't work, then your columns may be misnomers, suggesting a date ("created on"), when it's actually a datetime ("created at"). In Oracle such things happen more often than in other DBMS, because Oracle calls their datetime data type inappropriately just `DATE`. A `DATE` consists of a date part and a time part, and when dealing with dates only, we set that time part to midnight.

So, if you are storing times in your columns (e.g. `2014-04-12 at 12:34:56`), then you'll have to change the comparision, because `2014-04-12 12:34:56` does not equal `2014-04-12` (resp. `2014-04-12 00:00:00`).

```
select * 
from changerequests
where createdon >= date '2014-04-12' and createdon < date '2014-04-13'
and lastmodifiedon >= date '2014-05-17' and lastmodifiedon < date '2014-05-18';
```

Or you could truncate the datetimes to midnight (i.e. to mere dates). This may lead to a slower query, though, as the columns don't get accessed directly (and if you have an index on the date, that index cannot be used hence).

```
select * 
from changerequests
where trunc(createdon) = date '2014-04-12'
and trunc(lastmodifiedon) = date '2014-05-17';
```

Comment: the date `12-04-14` means `April 12, 2014`

Comment: In my table the date is stored as `12-04-14` so your above answer is not fetching any result

Comment: The date literal for April 12, 2014 is `date '2014-04-12'` obviously. Use that. Your date is not stored as `12-04-14`. A date has no inherent format. It is internally stored as some number, I guess. If you see `12-04-14` then this is how the tool you are using to retrieve the date displays it.

Comment: still the same, it's not fetching any rows

Comment: Then you may be storing datetimes (i.e. date + time). Please see my updated answer.